# Why was the background color of the two input different?

Tags: css, input

As can be seen,I didn't specify background color of input,but one is gray,ther other is white,why?

```
<style>
.baken {
    border:1px solid #888888;
    font-family:Trebuchet MS,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size:130%;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin:3px;
    padding:2px;
}

</style>


<input type="button" class="baken" value="answer your question"/>

<input type="button" value="hello button"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

By specifying a border on the button, it causes the default operating-system-specific styles on the button to be removed, reverting it to some default (which seems to be gray)

You can see this in action by removing the `border` from your class.

Comment: @jimr: Oi! Get out of my head! 8-)

Comment: Oh,I've never heard this kind of chained action before:)

Answer (score 1):

Because specifying a `border` makes the browser render the button itself using a basic visual style rather than using the operating system's themes.  Remove the `border` style and it will look like the other button.

Answer (score 0):

You should try a DOM inspector to see if it is inheriting colors from somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

The other thing to note on this, aside from the border bit, is that one of the inputs is defined using `class="baken"`, and the other is not. Therefore, the first input button will use the style you defined and show above; the other will use either the browser default or, if you've defined a tag-level `input` style, the defined style.

If both your inputs used the `baken` class, they'd look identical aside from the text, and be basic clickable gray boxes with your borders.

If neither used the `baken` class, they'd look identical aside from the text, and be the browser-default or `input` tag-defined default style.